# Update custom type property inside data context

Tags: wpf

The xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding EmailField.Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The datacontext:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private EmailModel _email = new EmailModel() {Email = "test@test.com"};

    public EmailModel EmailField
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set { _email = value; }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class EmailModel
{        
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Using the code above, I can see the valuue of EmailField.Email.

**The question:** what should I change to have possibility update the EmailField.Email from UI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to update the Email field with what you have - what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Setter breakpoint is not fired.

Comment: Do you mean the setter breakpoint on the EmailField property?

Comment: Yes. Value does not return to data context. If I use simple type property (string for example), it works proper.

Comment: Sorry if a stupid question, but you do mean the setter in EmailModel don't you? The setter in MainWindowViewModel will not fire since EmailField is not being changed.

Comment: Hm, this question has opened my eyes... How can I update EmailField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could directly set the `EmailField` property from the view would be to write an `IValueConverter` to convert from `string` (entered into the `TextBox`) to an `EmailModel`, but I wouldn't suggest that approach.

Why not instead add a property to your view model as below:

```
public string Email
{
    get { return _email.Email; }
    set
    {
        _email.Email = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Email"); //you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Then you can bind to the view model `Email` property, your internal email object will be updated correctly, and your view model will be notified in the property setter when the value is changed.